# How to get NextJS Url type for HOC?

Tags: next.js, react-typescript, emotion

I'm constructing a `Link` within a component, and need to accept `href` as a prop. However, I'm having issues defining that type.

```
import React from "react;
import Link, { LinkProps } from "next/link";

type MyComponentProps = {
  href: Pick<LinkProps, "href">
}

export const MyComponent: React.FC<MyComponentProps> = ({ href }) => (
  <Link href={href}>
    <a>Some Link Text</a>
  </Link>
);
```

I'm getting a type error:

```
  Type 'Pick<InternalLinkProps, "href">' is not assignable to type 'UrlObject'.
    Types of property 'href' are incompatible.
      Type 'Url' is not assignable to type 'string | null | undefined'.
        Type 'UrlObject' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
link.d.ts(6, 5): The expected type comes from property 'href' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { css?: Interpolation<Theme>; } & Omit<AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>, keyof InternalLinkProps> & InternalLinkProps & { ...; } & RefAttributes<...>'
```

How do I define the type for `href` in this Components props?

I saw [this resource](https://www.saltycrane.com/cheat-sheets/typescript/next.js/latest/), but it didnt help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick won't work here, since `Pick<LinkProps, "href">` would return an object that contains the link property, rather than just the value

I think you just want `LinkProps["href"]` but you can also use these:

```
type ComponentProps = Pick<LinkProps, "href">
type ComponentProps = Pick<LinkProps, "href"> & { ... otherProps}
```

Comment: the issue is that I actually have a few more props, I just simplified it for this example, eg `title` text is required as well

Comment: Oh so that's easy then just create a union then. See my edit.